# Making a opengl game with a moving UIImageview but i can get it to stop at edge of screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

Hi the title pre much sums it up, it is using the accelerometer but it just keeps going off the screen, im 15 and i am having heaps of trouble trying to get it to stop at the edge.here is my view controller.m file code.

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize person, delta;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIAccelerometer *accel =[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self;
    accel.updateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer
       didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{
    NSLog(@"x : %g", acceleration.x);
    NSLog(@"y : %g", acceleration.y);
    NSLog(@"z : %g", acceleration.z);

    delta.x = acceleration.y *50;
    //  delta.x = acceleration.x *8;


    person.center = CGPointMake(person.center.x + delta.x,person.center.y + delta.y );
     }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating `person.center` you need to cap it to the frame of your view, otherwise it will go off screen.

To get you started, this is how you might stop the person from going off the *left* edge of the view:

```
person.center = CGPointMake(person.center.x + delta.x,person.center.y + delta.y );
// add this
CGFloat leftOfWorld = 0.0f;
CGFloat minCenterX = leftOfWorld + (person.bounds.size.width / 2.0f);
person.center = CGPointMake(MAX(minCenterX, person.center.x), person.center.y);
```

The person is at the left of the screen when `center.x` is (width / 2) from the left edge. This is our minimum. We then take the larger value between the minimum and `center.x` so if `center.x` moves below this minimum, we change it.

You will probably want similar logic for the other edges of the screen. You will need to calculate the right and bottom edges of the screen using `self.view.width` and `self.view.height`.

Comment: i added that and now i get error expression is not assignable for this bit of code.   person.center.x = MAX(minCenterX, person.center.x);

Comment: and i only need it to stop left/right edges when it is in landscape.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you have to set the entire `center` value in one go. I updated the post.

Comment: Im having a problem making it work for the other side im getting multiple errors how can i fix this?